# Are rollbackFor exceptions thrown in @Transactional methods propagated?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Are `rollbackFor` exceptions thrown in `@Transactional` methods propagated (rethrown)? That is, is it more like

```java
catch (Exception e) {
    rollback();
}
```

or

```java
catch (Exception e) {
    rollback();
    throw e;
}
```

Sadly, I haven't found that information in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) for `@Transactional`

Comment: Exceptions are always propagated by Spring.